Как изменить цвет кнопок в приложении на смартфоне?
Я делаю приложение для вуза, в котором есть тестирование по курсам. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы цвет кнопок изменялся в зависимости от ответа пользователя (правильный – зеленый, неправильный – красный). В эмуляторе у меня все работает нормально, однако, когда я скачал приложение на свой смартфон, то у меня кнопки всегда одного цвета.
Вот кусок кода, отвечающий за изменение цвета кнопки:
private void verifyAnswer(Button button) {
    if (canAnswer){
        if(answer.equals(button.getText())) {
            button.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.color.green));
            correctAnswer++;
            answerFeedBackTv.setText("Верный ответ");
        } else {
            button.setBackground(getDrawable(getContext(),R.color.red));
            wrongAnswer++;
            answerFeedBackTv.setText("Неверный ответ");
        }
    }

Вот код xml-файл theme:
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.Diplom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/grey</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/grey</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>

        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>

Вот код кнопки xml:
<Button
        android:id="@+id/option1Btn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btbc"

        android:text="Option 1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/QsTv" />


ссылка

Не знаю как у вас это работает в эмуляторе, но идентификатор цвета не может быть использован вместо идентификатора изображения. Используйте для этого боле подходящие методы:
button.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.green));

